# flutter web deep linking when user click on notification

Tags: flutter, onclick, deep-linking

I want to open a specific page when the user clicks on a web notification. I check many articles and other things but I can't. can you please help me?

Comment: Have you checked https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking?

Comment: yes, but it is for android or ios and I want it for the web.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out Navigator 2.0 for this purpose. Have a look at https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is like when users get a notification on the web, the notification did not contain any URL or data, so I can't identify that this notification is for which one and which page is open for this type of notification. I can easily do it on android and on the web I am stuck I don't know-how may be some changes in the firesebase-sw.js file or index.html but I can't figure it out.